# Поиск в текстовом файле  и копирование найденного в другой

Tags: поиск, файлы, строки, c++

Нужно найти в **A.txt** все слова с буквой "**Й**" скопировать слова в файл **B.txt** 
Каждое слово в **B.txt** начинается с новой строки.
Подскажите как это сделать. Желательно пример с кодом.

Comment: и еще, кстати, если вам надо именно на с++, то не плохо бы в теги добавить с++. Это я уж сделаю за вас, но в первый и последний раз...

Comment: >Это я уж сделаю за вас, но в первый и последний раз...

поразительное великодушие

Answer (score 1):

1. Считать файл **A.txt**
2. разбить строку, в которую считали файл по словам
3. В каждом полученном слове искать букву "Й"
4. записывать слова, в которых есть эта буква в массив.
5. сохранить построчно массив в файл **B.txt**.

Что из этого не получается? 
Я же надеюсь, что вы не хотите, что бы вашу лабораторку сделали за вас?

Comment: Хочу:)
не получается после того как найдена Й скопировать это слово.

Comment: @Татьяна Агиуллова, если хотите, что бы сделали за вас - обращайтесь на фриланс, там недорого. А тут помогают тем, кто хочет сделать сам.   
Если хотите, что бы вам помогли, а не сделали за вас, то выкладывайте сюда свой код.

Comment: @Татьяна Агиуллова, еще кстати,  Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся.

Comment: мне стыдно выкладывать свой код)

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 SetConsoleCP(1251);
 SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

 char string[100];

 ifstream fin("text.txt");
 fin.getline(string, 100);
 char * dog = strchr(string, 'Й');
 
        что делать дальше ума не приложу.


 fin.close();
 system("pause >> void");
 return 0;
}